# Why does Jedi: Fallen Order runs so smooth?

Tags: performance, framerate, star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

*disclaimer: I'm new to PC gaming and this question may be dumb, but I couldn't find anything online*

Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order isn't a game known for its optimization. My friend, playing with a GTX1050Ti, warned me of this, saying he could push it to 45 fps on medium. I decided to give it a try anyway on my new PC with a GTX970, and the game runs at a smooth 60 fps on epic quality. Is this normal?

Comment: What is wrong with having *good* performance? Aren't asking the opposite of what you really want and perhaps want to help your friend a bit?

Comment: @mindstormsboi nothing is wrong with it, I'm very happy about it. Since I'm not an expert, I wanted to know if this big difference is random, or if it happens with most games.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. Your GTX 970 is faster than the GTX 1050 Ti.

Nvidia GPUs are named after following scheme:

| Full Name | Prefix | Series | Tier | Revision | Suffix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GTX 970 | GTX | 9 | 7 | 0 |  |
| GTX 1050 Ti | GTX | 10 | 5 | 0 | Ti |

#### Prefix

There are currently 3 prefixes:

- GT: Reserved for the bottom-tier cards, such as Tier 4 or lower. The most recent examples being the GT 1010 and GT 1030.
- GTX: What most Nvidia GPUs used to be.
- RTX: The successor to GTX cards. They all support Hardware Accelerated Ray Tracing.

#### Series

Higher series cards are newer, and therefore offer more features and are generally more powerful than older series cards **from the same Tier**.

#### Tier

This tells you how powerful the card is. The higher, the better. Comparing different Tiers from different Series is not straightforward, but as a general rule: Each new Series is roughly 1 Tier better than the old series.

For instance, a GTX 970 is roughly the same speed as a GTX 1060. This is not always true, but serves as a good estimate of performance across different series.

#### Suffix

There are currently 3 suffixes:

- Ti: Refers to a more powerful variant of the GPU. These GPU's are still slower than GPUs of a higher Tier. For example, a GTX 1050 Ti is more powerful than a GTX 1050, but less powerful than a GTX 1060.
- Super: Essentially a cheaper and slower Ti variant.
- M: Refers to mobile GPUs. These GPUs are usually much slower than their non-mobile counterparts, so a direct comparison is very difficult.

---

As you can see, your friend's GTX 1050 Ti is close in speed to a GTX 960, which is slower than a GTX 970.

If you search for comparisons, you can find several sites confirming that the GTX 1050 Ti is slower than the GTX 970:

- According to [UserBenchmark](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1050-Ti-vs-Nvidia-GTX-970/3649vs2577), the GTX 970 is 62% faster than the GTX 1050 Ti.
- According to [GRAPHICS CARDS ADVISOR](https://graphicscardsadvisor.com/gtx-1050-ti-vs-gtx-970/), the GTX 970 is 40 % faster than the GTX 1050 Ti.

So there's absolutely nothing odd about the GTX 970 being faster than the GTX 1050 Ti.

Comment: Wow, like just wow! Thank you for this outstanding answer I learned something that I didn’t even know I was missing. Also thank you for keeping this up to date with your recent edit.

Comment: @ahsteele, I'm happy you liked my answer. It makes me glad that I put in the effort.